# trying to covert json to csv ,index_col error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

trying to import a json file to csv
but its showing error

```
import pandas as pd
eros=pd.read_json('E:\\gautam bhaiya\\pandas\\netflix_data (13).json',index_col=0)
eros.to_csv("new.csv")
```

TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index_col'

Comment: the error is telling you that `read_json` doesnot accept a parameter called `index_col`, did you see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) ?

Comment: in my csv file its showing a column for index when i'm not using index_col

Comment: to_csv is not same as read_json, use `to_csv(index=False)` when writing this to csv

Comment: @robin Add Some sample data of `json` data files.

Comment: @anky and how i can one of column as a index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `read_json` does not have an `index_col` argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

If you want to set the index after importing from a JSON file, you may use the `set_index` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

When exporting to CSV you may also omit the index using `.to_csv(index=false)`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: but in my csv file the first column is of index

Comment: how can i remove it?

Comment: In this case you may set `eros.to_csv(index=false)` when exporting to CSV: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html